# Mapping string into db to java class

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have an entity class (account), with a column called permission, to manage the access on my website. It's mapped as string in my db, like the follow:

```
@Column(length = 300)
private String permissions;
```

In truth, this field contains a json string, for example like:

```
{"permissionOne" : true, "permissionTwo" : false}
```

The field is not mapped as JSON, because my db is MySql with an older version, which doesn't support JSON type, and I cannot change the version.

I have also a JsonHelper class:

```
public class JsonHelper {

    /** Singleton parser instance */
    private static ObjectMapper parser = new ObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .enable(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS);

    /** Logger instance */
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonHelper.class);

    /**
     * converts one java object into json {@link String}g
     *
     * @param toConvert
     * @return converted {@link String} object
     */
    public static String toJsonString(Object toConvert) {

        String result = null;
        try {
            result = parser.writeValueAsString(toConvert);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot parse value : " + toConvert + " StackTrace : ", e);

        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts one json {@link String} into java object
     *
     * @param toConvert json string to convert
     * @param convertType class type to be converted into
     * @return converted java object
     */
    public static <T> T fromJsonString(String toConvert, Class<T> convertType) {

        if (toConvert == null) return null;

        T result = null;

        try {
            result = parser.readValue(toConvert, convertType);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot parse value : " + convertType + " " + toConvert + " StackTrace : ", e);

        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts one java object to {@link JsonNode}
     *
     * @param toConvert object to convert
     * @return converted json object
     */
    public static JsonNode toJsonNode(Object toConvert) {

        return parser.valueToTree(toConvert);

    }

    /**
     * Converts one {@link JsonNode} into java object
     *
     * @param toConvert to be converted
     * @param convertType type of class to convert to
     * @return converted java object
     */
    public static <T> T fromJsonNode(JsonNode toConvert, Class<T> convertType) {

        T result = null;

        try {
            result = parser.treeToValue(toConvert, convertType);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot parse value : " + convertType + " " + toConvert + 
    " StackTrace : ", e);
        }

        return result;

    }

    /**
     * Converts one json into list of objects
     *
     * @param toConvert json to convert
     * @param convertType list type
     * @return converted liist with objects
     */
    public static <T> List<T> fromJsonNodeList(JsonNode toConvert, Class<T> 
    convertType) {

        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!toConvert.isArray()) return result;

        for (JsonNode node : toConvert) {
            result.add(fromJsonNode(node, convertType));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static ObjectMapper getParser() {
        return parser;
    }

}
```

When I do:

```
Permission permission = JsonHelper.fromJsonString(account.getPermissions(), Permission.class);
```

permission variable is null.

I don't know why. It seems all good.
Am I missing something?

Can I do it in a different way?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what I see in this piece of code:

```
public static <T> T fromJsonString(String toConvert, Class<T> convertType) {

    if (toConvert == null) return null;

    T result = null;

    try {
        result = parser.readValue(toConvert, convertType);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Cannot parse value : " + convertType + " " + toConvert + " StackTrace : ", e);

    }

    return result;
}
```

this method can only return `null` in case `toConvert` is `null` or the parser cannot read the value.

In case `toConvert` is `null` is an acceptable option (assuming the `permissions` field is really optional). You should perhaps log a warning that the `toConvert` parameter is null. Apart from that you could use Java 8's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as a return value here.

In the other case there is probably some garbage (non readable JSON) in your database and this will require some cleanup action apart from logging. You should try to avoid to have data in your storage which will persistently cause errors.

Comment: toConvert is not null. In the DB the string is a valid JSON: {"accessAllVisits": true,"accessAllDocuments": false}

Comment: @Gjord83: then you should see a message in the logs, right?

Comment: @Gjord83: Can you change the code to throw an exception if `toConvert` is `null` using `Objects.requireNonNull(toConvert, "toConvert should not be null");` And see, if that exception is thrown?